# appending strings to a slice recursively causes out of memory error in golang

Tags: go, out-of-memory, slice

I'm trying to parse an HTML page and print its links.
I'm going over the parsed Html tree recursively adding links to a slice of strings.
I'm missing something out as I get **out of memory error**

here is my code:

```
package parser

import (
    "errors"
    "io"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

//URLParser returns all the urls inside a html page
type URLParser struct {
}

//GetURLS returns all
func (URLParser) GetURLS(htmlInput io.Reader) (*[]string, error) {

    result := []string{}
    htmlRoot, err := html.Parse(htmlInput)
    //result := make([]string, 1000)

    if err != nil {
        parserError := errors.New("html parser failed with error" + err.Error())
        return nil, parserError
    }

    finalResult := traverseHTMLTree(htmlRoot, &result)
    return finalResult, nil
}

func traverseHTMLTree(node *html.Node, result *[]string) *[]string {

    if node == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if isLinkElement(node) {
        currlink, shouldUse := getURLAttrb(node.Attr)
        if shouldUse {

            *result = append(*result, currlink)
        }

    }

    for currNode := node.FirstChild; currNode != nil; currNode = currNode.NextSibling {
        currRest := traverseHTMLTree(currNode, result)
        if currRest != nil {
            *result = append(*currRest, *result...)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func getURLAttrb(attr []html.Attribute) (string, bool) {
    for i := 0; i < len(attr); i++ {
        if attr[i].Key == "href" {
            return attr[i].Val, true
        }
    }
    return "", false
}

func isLinkElement(node *html.Node) bool {
    if node.Type == html.ElementNode {
        if node.Data == "a" {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

When just trying to print the links to stdout it works perfectly, so it got to be something with the way I handle the slice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each node in the HTML tree, you're adding the contents of the results array to itself, recursively. That should grow pretty quickly.

Note that when you check if `isLinkElement`, you add the item to the result list.

Then for each element of the html tree, you append the contents of the results array to itself, doubling it.

You're passing a pointer to a slice. You're effectively using a single slice for the whole program, and keep adding to it. What you're returning from the traverseHTMLTree is the same slice, not a copy of it. So it keeps growing.

One way to fix it is: do not pass the pointer to the slice. Pass the current slice, update it, and return the new slice.

Comment: passing the slice (and not a pointer to it) will cause copying the current slice every time, no?

Comment: No. Passing an array will. Passing a slice will not.

Comment: To be more clear, passing a slice will copy the slice, which is (pointer, len, cap). It will not copy the underlying array.

Comment: basically removing the "*" from anywhere in the code? still getting out of memory

Comment: That's not what I said. You're still doubling the array for every element. Remove this: `*result = append(*currRest, *result...)`